# jQuery-UI tabs not working on some pages

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, debugging, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a site set up in Wordpress, and using the same template on two pages, one of the jQuery-UI tabs work and the other doesnt. Can anybody help me debug and find out where the second page have a conflict?

Working: http://solstad.no/investor-relations/general-meetings/

Not Working: http://solstad.no/investor-relations/financial-reports/

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `data-toggle="tab"` to the tabs in the 2nd link and it should work.

See screenshot -

[image]

Since, it's a Wordpress site, I'm not sure if you're calling the jQuery UI javascript correctly or implementing the tabs the right way. But adding the following script anywhere below that tab content should work / hot-fix it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.nav-tabs li a').attr('data-toggle', 'tab');
</script>
```